# CSS - Constant size of border image

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

**DESCRIPTION:**
Im trying to get constant size of border image when resizing div. I'm thinking of solving this with pseudo elements, but is there way to make things easier?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h3>Resizable</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background: white;
}
#resizable {
  border: 25px solid !important;
  border-image: url(https://svgur.com/i/9c2.svg) 15 round !important;
  background: white
}
```

**VISUAL:**

[image]

**JSFIDDLE:**
https://jsfiddle.net/3twuq14z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jus add this property to your svg file: `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` to SVG path. Take a look at here (I re-uploaded your svg file): https://jsfiddle.net/dswLmaxo/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do:

```js
$("#resizable").resizable({
 aspectRatio: 9/ 9,
 });
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
}
#resizable {
  border: 25px solid transparent;
  border-image: url(https://svgur.com/i/9c2.svg) 30 round;
  background: white;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resizable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <h3>Resizable</h3>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3twuq14z/2/